# Installing MySQLon the AWD server giving error

Tags: mysql, package, systemd, requires

I am installing the MySQL 5.7 on the AWS server. Its giving this error:

> Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.7.15-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
>
> Requires: systemd

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to install systemd on an existing Amazon server.  You will have to spin up a new server that has it installed.  Something like an ubuntu instance.